# What are MSI interrupt domains an why are they needed?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, interrupt, interrupt-handling

In latest kernel I see MSI interrupt domain. These API's are being implemented for supporting MSI interrupts and an irq hierarchy manner.

```
struct irq_domain *pci_msi_create_irq_domain(struct fwnode_handle *fwnode,
                                             struct msi_domain_info *info,
                                              struct irq_domain *parent)
```

Here in the last parent parameter we are sending parent domain, created using `irq_domain_add_linear`.

I would like to know why do we need two domains to handle MSI?